# What does it mean by live bindings?

Tags: javascript, binding, es6-modules

I am following a tutorial and it says

> ES modules uses live bindings. It means a feature to support cyclical
>   dependencies.

But I don't clearly understand this concept. What does this mean?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What is ESM?

Comment: I think ESM meant ES Modules @barmar

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Live bindings is a concept introduced in ES modules. It means that when the exporting module changes a value, the change will be visible from the importer side. This is not the case for CommonJS modules. Module exports are copied in CommonJS. Hence importing modules cannot see changes happened on the exporter side.

---

### ESM

### counter.mjs

```
export let count = 1;
export function increment() {
    ++count;
}
```

### index.mjs

```
import { count, increment } from './counter.mjs';
console.log(count);
increment();
console.log(count);
```

### Output

```
$ node --experimental-modules index.mjs
1
2
```

---

### CJS

### counter.js

```
let count = 1;
function increment() {
    ++count;
}

exports.count = count;
exports.increment = increment;
```

### index.js

```
const { count, increment } = require('./counter.js');
console.log(count);
increment();
console.log(count);
```

### Output

```
$ node index.js
1
1
```

---

More resources on the topic:

- [What do ES6 modules export?](https://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) by Axel Rauschmayer
- [ES modules: A cartoon deep-dive](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/) by Lin Clark
- [Chapter on Modules in Exploring JS](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) by Axel Rauschmayer

Comment: Worth noting that Live Bindings provide a common memory address for both exporter & importer, i.e. both are pointing to the same memory location.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong. In commonJS, the change done by the exporter is actually reflected everywhere. Your `increment` function in the CJS example should mutate exports.count instead. And then the change is reflected everywhere.

Comment: `Module exports are copied in CommonJS` is wrong. The object called "exports" is exported to every file that use require(), and any change made on that object is reflected in every file that used require()

Comment: the function should be `function increment() {
   export.count += 1
}`

Answer (score 0):

in CJS, `require("./foo")` gets you a reference to the `exports` object of `foo.js`.

1. let's set `exports.x` to 0 in `foo.js`

```js
exports.x = 0
```

2. In `bar.js` we get a reference to foo's exports and mutate it:

```js
const fooExports = require("./foo")
fooExports.x += 1
```

Now we put everything in action in `main.js`

```js
const fooExports = require("./foo") // getting a reference to exports
console.log(fooExports.x) // x is indeed 0
require("./bar") // we execute bar.js that mutate exports
console.log(fooExports.x) // x is now 1, because fooExports is a reference to exports
```

TLDR: What we receive from `require` **is not a copy**. It's a reference to the `exports` object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe additionally noteworthy would be support for "live bindings" in plain old javascript if one actually wanted that.

```js
var o = { x: 5 }

function increment () { o.x++ }

with (o) {
  console.log(x) // 5
  increment()
  console.log(x) // 6
}
```

So you could write modules and wrappers to get the wanted behavior without using ESM.